# mapwithstae word count..do states lock for a particular key

Tags: spark-streaming

I am just following the mapwithstae word count on [databrick website](https://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/spark/1.6/examples/Streaming%20mapWithState.html)..I have a conceptual question.

```
def trackStateFunc(batchTime: Time, key: String, value: Option[Int], state: State[Long]): Option[(String, Long)] = {
val sum = value.getOrElse(0).toLong + state.getOption.getOrElse(0L)
val output = (key, sum)
state.update(sum)
Some(output)
}
```

I assune that when the streaming application enters this function, it locks the sates for a particular key..so if an identical key is retrived from other parttions and wanna update the sates..it doesnt read an old state value?

or maybe it is better to say all items (values) related to identical keys are processed in one parttiion?